# Set easter on statsmodel.tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis

Tags: python, statsmodels, x13

I am trying to migrate some code from `R` to `Python` but, in order to do that, I need to seasonally adjust some time series. I've compared the outputs from the `seasonal` package in `R` and the `statsmodels` package from `Python` and they differ a bit even though they both use the `x13` program.

According to this thread https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3549 the difference is that the `R` package uses by default trading days and easter in its spec file.

The `statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis` documentation (https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.x13.x13_arima_analysis.html) has an explicit parameter for the trading days but it doesn't seem to have one for other variable settings such as easter holiday.

Is it possible to set this in this python function or does it still have to be implemented?